# Android Studio Firebase Images cause OOM

Tags: java, android, performance, firebase, android-studio

currently I am developing a simple social media app that I am having some issues with. My app can work perfectly if it wasn't for an OOM (Out of Memory). I have realised through logcat why I was getting this message and why my app wasn't displaying images after some testing.

I ran the Android Profiler on my app to see what was going on, and I started to switch around the activities, make a post and load up some previous posts. I noticed that my memory was steadily increasing and at around 500mb my app stopped displaying images.

My memory doesn't decrease and every time I load an image it will increase significantly. I am using fragments to navigate through a feed that loads a user's post, and I also have a settings button that will take the user to a new settings activity. If the memory reaches around 500mb all of the images on each fragment and in the settings will not load.

I am using Firebase storage to get the images. I use Firebase to get text also for the Username, Email etc and it seems to load perfectly.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? it takes only around a minute of activity to reach 500mb

Here is how I load my Images in the settings activity, In the activity where I get the post feed it uses module classes so I won't paste all that code here and I have already tested it. The images on both activities will always load the same way. Anyway here is my settings activity for getting the profileimage,

```
     eventListener = UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("username")){
                String Username =  dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                username.setText(Username);
            }
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage")){
                String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.user_circle2).into(profileImage);
                endListener();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    }

private void endListener() {
    UserRef.removeEventListener(eventListener);
}
```

Please can somebody tell me how I am meant to fix this. Image Compression? Garbage Collection? I need some advice, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use [Glide for Android](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)?

Comment: I have researched, but apparently picasso is faster

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to explicitly call `image.dispose()` when you are done with an image. This is so because images are not loaded in the java memory heap and hence are not garbage collected.